# Different color interpreter for Planet Images

Tags: raster, gdal, planet

I'm trying to merge a set of Planet Imagery with gdal, but I'm getting `Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support heterogeneous band characteristics. Skipping ./out2.tif`.

After checking gdalinfo I realized that Blue and Red color are swapped between band 1 and 3 in some images. How is this possible? How can it be fixed?

Actually the solution can be to rewrite all the images using `gdal_translate -colorinterp blue,green,red,undefined`. But I'm still interested in knowing how this is possible.

Comment: I would ask that from Planet if images are their original products.

Comment: It may not be a problem of interpretation. That is, the first band of some datasets may be blue. Don't assume it must be the red one. If you are going to sense infrared, it makes sense to order blue, green, red, infrared.